# Storing and processing output while defishing fisheye image into DMA is difficult

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I have file in which output of Fish-eye image co-ordinates are present and next I need to push this co-ordinates to another interface where the normalization is done and defishing image is obtained.
Currently I have X,Y co-ordinates to fish-eye image and a,b,c,d neighboring values to the respective pixel. In total the length of these values are around 16MB.
Currently I am having only 16MB of DMA,so I am looking for better approach where I can get a block approach to this values.
Can any one please help me in getting better approach.
Image resolution is 1280 x 800.

Comment: What does "DMA" refer to in this case?

Comment: DMA is actually memory interface used to transfer the data avoiding the CPU interface.